# Using Open CL with AMD Radeon R9390 not possible - why? (QGIS 3.4)

Tags: qgis

I recently found out that you can activate OpenCL acceleration in QGIS 3.4. But QGIS can't find any device which is compatible. I checked my GPU, which is a Radeon R9 390 (16GB) and in the GPU's sofware menu it sais "OpenCL™ Version 22.19.677.257". 
So shouldn't it actually support OpenCL? If yes - why can I not find and activate it in QGIS?